# Install error when installing zeromq in npm/node-red

Tags: npm, node-red

I have challenges installing zeromq in Node-RED, module I try to install: node-red-contrib-zeromq. I get the same error running this in Debian as in Alpine docker.
Node-RED is installed in Debian.

I get following error logs:

[image: Logs1]

[image: Logs2]

[image: Logs3]

Install node-red-contrib-zeromq in Node-RED.

Comment: Please do not post images of text, they are very hard to read, impossible for users of screen readers and not searchable. Post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree, the challenge was when I added the log, Stack Overflow thought it was code and wanted me to alter the "code".. so I did and then it urged me to comment on the code.. (I coulden't publish) I gave up! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have the required build tools for npm to build the native component of the zero mq node.

The import line is `Error: not found: make`

This means that you do not have the tool `make` installed. Assuming you are on a ubuntu/debian based system you need to run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

This also assumes you are not using the official node-red docker containers as those tools are included.